# How to scale a group of different sized UV faces to all be the same size as each other?

Tags: uv

What is the quickest way to scale a group of UV faces of various sizes, so that they all become the same size/aspect ratio as each other? Please see the image below for an example of what I want to achieve in as few steps as possible.

On the left of the image is a group of different sized UV faces (the result of a Smart UV Project) and on the right is what I want; the same UV faces but all the same scale as each other.

[image]

I scaled and aligned the faces on the right manually, but I was wondering if there was some sort of shortcut or tool which automates this process, instead of having to resize each UV face one-by-one? I've tried the addons UV Align/Distribute and Magic UV, but I couldn't find any options to achieve this effect.

Thanks in advance